# Reference request for research on the maximum drawdown **ratio** (NOT value)

Tags: stochastic-processes, risk, brownian-motion, reference-request, drawdown

Let's suppose the asset price process follows a Geometric Brownian motion $S_t \sim GBM(\mu, \sigma),\,t\ge 0$, and define the two process:
$$
\begin{align}
\text{MSF}_t &:= \max_{\tau\in[0,t]} S_\tau\\
\text{MDD_Ratio}_t &: = \max_{\tau\in[0,t]} ((\text{MSF}_\tau- S_\tau) / \text{MSF}_\tau)
\end{align}
$$
where MSF means "maximum so far" and MDD means maximum drawdown. As $S_t$ is forever positive, we see that MDD_Ratio is always well defined.

Is there any research done on the distribution, or at least the mean value of MDD_Ratio?

For what I saw, most research literature on DD seems to focus on the max drawdown **value**, i.e., $\max_{0\le t\le T}(\text{MSF}_t - S_t)$ (and most of the time the asset price process is assumed to follow a BM instead of a GBM), instead of maximum drawdown **ratio** whch IMHO is much commoner in practice.

Comment: Do you mean $S_{\tau}$ in your second equation?

Comment: @Gordon yes. All should be $\tau$ instead.

Comment: @vim please allow me to ask **"why you ask?"**. From an investor's perspective the series *[+1,+5,-1]* and *[+1,-1,+5]* have different *mdd ratios* but are equally risky. Aren't they, in your opinion?

Comment: @elemolotiv I assume you're talking about the percentages of return. Then your examples have the same mdd ratio (-1%).

Comment: @elemolotiv MDD ratios are very important both to investors and sometimes also to regulators. Let's consider a risky fund: if at some point the MDD ratio reaches an intolerable point for investors (say 10%), they will withdraw; if the MDD ratio reaches some regulatory threshold (say 20%), the fund may be forced to close down.

Comment: @vim: yes! I meant return series. So let's convert to cumulative returns, i.e. random walks. We have $walk_A=[0,1,6,5]$, $mdd_A=-1$, $mddratio_A=\frac{-1}{6}=-16.7\%$. While $walk_B=[0,1,0,5]$, $mdd_B=-1$, $mddratio_B=\frac{-1}{+1}=-100\%$. Two walks with the same $mdd$, but different $mddratio$. Just $walk_B$ was unluckier because the drawdown occurred earlier, but that doesn't mean $walk_B$ will be worse than $walk_A$ in the future, if they originate from the same return distribution.

Comment: @elemolotiv not sure how you got the mdd ratios like this. I assumed the first return series is [1%, 5%, -1%], what does [0, 1, 6, 5] stand for?

Comment: @Vim - apparently I need to refine my thought, I'm used to reason with profits not returns, so I mixed up some parts. Sorry for making you spend time around this conversation with me ‍♂️